# Hosting a Form's content inside of another Form?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, iframe

I need to host a Windows Form inside another Form, like an `iframe` in HTML. However, using a Multi-Document Interface causes the Form's window controls to be rendered as well. I need *only* the content of the Form to be rendered. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an application like this.

For the contained form, I set .TopLevel = false, the formBorderStyle to none and I also set the Dock property to Fill.

In my parent form, I have a split panel and I just add my contained form to the the panel I want it in.

I don't remember exactly why I didn't want to go with UserControls any more, it was years ago. I seem to recall having a reason though. Some of my contained forms use UserControls.

Answer (score 4):

Look into UserControls.  They will accomplish what you want.

Comment: im new to C#, which UserControl?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you make each game a separate `UserControl`?

Comment: @EfeOzturkoglu - make your own.